# View from model and controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
        **Controller file i have form_ctrl.php and code given below**
        <?php
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class form_ctrl extends CI_Controller {

            public function index()
            {
                //$this->load->view('welcome_message');
                     $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
                     $this->load->library('form_validation');
                     $this->load->model('data_model');

                        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Username', 'required');
                      $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name','required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
                        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required',
                                array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
                        );
                        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
                        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'required');
                        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address','required|min_length[5]');

                        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                        {
                                $this->load->view('table');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                              $this->load->view('results');
                                $name=$this->input->post('name');
                                $pass=$this->input->post('pass');
                                 $email=$this->input->post('email');
                                $mobile=$this->input->post('mobile');
                                $address=$this->input->post('address');
                                     $data = array(
                                                   'name' =>$name ,
                                                   'pass' => $pass,
                                                   'email' => $email,
                                                   'mobile' => $mobile,
                                                   'address' => $address
                                                   );
                                    $this->data_model->insert_fun('form', $data);

                                               }
                }
         function GetAll()
          {
             $this->load->model('emp_model');
               $data['query']=$this->emp_model->emp_getall();
               $this->load->view('emp_viewall',$data);
          }

              }


    **model file i have data_model.php**

    <?php
    class data_model extends CI_Model {

        function __construct() { 
            parent::__construct (); 
        }

        public function insert_fun($tableName,$data){

           return $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);

        }
    function emp_getall()
      {
           $this->load->database();
           $query=$this->db->get('form');
           return $query->result();
      }
    }


    ?>


view file i have results.php

<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Mobile</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Action</td>
</tr>
 <?php
foreach($query as $row)
{
  print_r($row);exit;

}
?> 
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>


</table>


</body>
</html>
```

data is inserting properly but view not showing the database fields it means IN model file function (function emp_getall()) orin controller file (function GetAll()) is not working give me the solution where error in this code...

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetAll()
          {
             $this->load->model('emp_model');
               $data['query']=$this->emp_model->emp_getall();
               $this->load->view('results',$data);
          }
```

you wrong view call check this

Comment: bro you print_r in controller you get record or not check after pass data in your view

Comment: hothi jimit bro i m newbe in codeigniter but its not working not getting any value

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>   <head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Mobile</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Action</td>
</tr>
 <?php
foreach($query as $row) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->mobile;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->address;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->action;?></td>
</tr>


</table>
<?php endforeach ?>

</body>
</html>
```

try this once .............